# Right align using tabulary

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabulary

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openany]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{m{3.7cm} m{8cm} m{4cm}}
        \textbf{Tarea} & \textbf{Descripcion} & \textbf{Tiempo estimado} \\ [1ex]
        Análisis & Recopilación de requisitos & 12 h. \\ 
        Diseño & Diseño a alto nivel de la aplicación & 20 h. \\ 
        AppPreferences & Diseño e implementación del menú de preferencias de la aplicación & 10 h. \\ 
        MainActivity & Diseño e implementación de la actividad principal de la aplicación & 16 h. \\
        Dashboard & Diseño e implementación del fragmento del dashboard & 34 h. \\
        LocalXBee & Diseño e implementación del fragmento del XBee local & 20 h. \\
        XBeeNetwork & Diseño e implementación del fragmento de la red de Xbees & 24 h.\\
        Log & Diseño e implementación del fragmento de registro de sucesos & 6 h.\\
        BackgroundService & Diseño e implementación del servicio en segundo plano de la aplicación & 40 h.\\
        Servicio AIDL & Creación de la interfaz AIDL y wrappers necesarios & 10 h.\\
        Peticiones RCI & Diseño e implementación del sistema de procesamiento y respuesta de las peticiones RCI & 20 h.\\
        Pruebas & Realización de pruebas de integración de la aplicación antes del cierre del proyecto & 20 h.\\
        Documentación & Documentación del código & 6 h.\\
        Reuniones & Reuniones de seguimiento y control con los tutores de la empresa & 20 h.\\
        Memoria & Realización del documento para el Trabajo Fin de Grado & 30 h.\\
        Presentación & Realización de las diapositivas y preparación de la defensa ante el tribunal & 12 h.\\[1ex]
        \textbf{Total} & &  \textbf{300} \\

    \end{tabulary} 

    \caption{Descomposición del proyecto en tareas.}
    \label{tab:planificacion}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

I would like to have the last column text right aligned. How can I achieve that?

Comment: replace `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}` by `begin{tabular}`, as  `tabulary` can not do anything useful here as you have fixed width columns, then replace the last `m{1.5cm}` by `r`

Comment: your code has four columns and your image has three, are they really related?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I make that changes, i get some errors: http://i.imgur.com/1NoZnXs.png

Comment: Wrong image, sorry. Fixed

Comment: It is always best to make your example code a complete document so that people can test answers (and you can post the resulting output as image)

Comment: You did not make the suggested change, you left in `{\textwidth}`

Comment: for the table in the new image I would not use tabulary or p or m columns at all: it is just numeric data so use `\begin{tabular}{lrrr}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for all the trouble =( I have updated the question with the correct code (a full working document) and an image.

Comment: @Trollkemada Just replace the last `m{4cm}` by `R`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi then the table goes out of margins.

Comment: @Trollkemada then you have to make the other columns thinner. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current table is quite hard to read so I would like to propose a completely different approach:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{table}{1}
\begin{table}
\robustify\bfseries
\centering
\sisetup{detect-weight}
    \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=-2.2]}
    %\toprule % optional, if you like it
        \textbf{Tarea} & \textbf{Estimación} en h. & \textbf{Dedicación} en h. & \textbf{Desviación} en \si{\percent} \\\addlinespace % or \midrule
        Análisis &    12 & 8  &  -33\\
        Diseño &    20 & 18 &  -10\\
        AppPreferences &  10 & 12 &  20\\
        MainActivity & 16 & 14 & -12\\
        Dashboard &  34 & 40 & 17\\
        LocalXBee &  20 & 35 & 75\\
        XBeeNetwork & 24 & 14 &  -58\\
        Log &   6 & 20 & 233\\
        BackgroundService &  40 & 42 & 5\\
        Servicio AIDL &   10 & 12 & 20\\
        Peticiones RCI &  20 & 16 & -20\\
        Pruebas &    20 & 10 & -50\\
        Documentación &   6 & 4  & -33\\
        Reuniones &    20 & 17 & -15\\
        Memoria &    30 & 34 & 13\\
        Presentación &   12 & 10 & -16\\\addlinespace % or \midrule
        \textbf{Total} & \bfseries 300 & \bfseries 302 & \bfseries 0,67 \\
        %\bottomrule % optional, if you like it
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Tiempos planificados, dedicados y desviaciones de las distintas tareas.}
    \label{tab:control}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Nota bene that the value of the very last cell would have surprised me as a reader of your article.

---

**Update**: as you have provided a completely new table in your question, I have a new MWE here. I have adapted your table in order to use `tabulary` and its `L` and `R` columns (please read the manual). But I have also given a solution without that package, as I do not think it is needed here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{ragged2e,microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}L L R@{}}
        \textbf{Tarea} & \textbf{Descripción} & \textbf{Tiempo estimado} \\ [1ex]
        Análisis & Recopilación de requisitos & 12 h. \\ 
        Diseño & Diseño a alto nivel de la aplicación & 20 h. \\ 
        AppPreferences & Diseño e implementación del menú de preferencias de la aplicación & 10 h. \\ 
        MainActivity & Diseño e implementación de la actividad principal de la aplicación & 16 h. \\
        Dashboard & Diseño e implementación del fragmento del dashboard & 34 h. \\
        LocalXBee & Diseño e implementación del fragmento del XBee local & 20 h. \\
        XBeeNetwork & Diseño e implementación del fragmento de la red de Xbees & 24 h.\\
        Log & Diseño e implementación del fragmento de registro de sucesos & 6 h.\\
        BackgroundService & Diseño e implementación del servicio en segundo plano de la aplicación & 40 h.\\
        Servicio AIDL & Creación de la interfaz AIDL y wrappers necesarios & 10 h.\\
        Peticiones RCI & Diseño e implementación del sistema de procesamiento y respuesta de las peticiones RCI & 20 h.\\
        Pruebas & Realización de pruebas de integración de la aplicación antes del cierre del proyecto & 20 h.\\
        Documentación & Documentación del código & 6 h.\\
        Reuniones & Reuniones de seguimiento y control con los tutores de la empresa & 20 h.\\
        Memoria & Realización del documento para el Trabajo Fin de Grado & 30 h.\\
        Presentación & Realización de las diapositivas y preparación de la defensa ante el tribunal & 12 h.\\[1ex]
        \textbf{Total} & &  \textbf{300} \\
    \end{tabulary} 
    \caption{Descomposición del proyecto en tareas.}
    \label{tab:planificacion}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\robustify\bfseries
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l >{\RaggedRight}p{5.87cm} @{}S[table-format=3.0,detect-weight]@{}}
        \textbf{Tarea} & \textbf{Descripción} & \textbf{Tiempo est.\ (h.)} \\\addlinespace
        Análisis & Recopilación de requisitos & 12 \\ 
        Diseño & Diseño a alto nivel de la aplicación & 20 \\ 
        AppPreferences & Diseño e implementación del menú de preferencias de la aplicación & 10 \\ 
        MainActivity & Diseño e implementación de la actividad principal de la aplicación & 16 \\
        Dashboard & Diseño e implementación del fragmento del dashboard & 34 \\
        LocalXBee & Diseño e implementación del fragmento del XBee local & 20 \\
        XBeeNetwork & Diseño e implementación del fragmento de la red de Xbees & 24\\
        Log & Diseño e implementación del fragmento de registro de sucesos & 6\\
        BackgroundService & Diseño e implementación del servicio en segundo plano de la aplicación & 40\\
        Servicio AIDL & Creación de la interfaz AIDL y wrappers necesarios & 10\\
        Peticiones RCI & Diseño e implementación del sistema de procesamiento y respuesta de las peticiones RCI & 20\\
        Pruebas & Realización de pruebas de integración de la aplicación antes del cierre del proyecto & 20\\
        Documentación & Documentación del código & 6\\
        Reuniones & Reuniones de seguimiento y control con los tutores de la empresa & 20\\
        Memoria & Realización del documento para el Trabajo Fin de Grado & 30\\
        Presentación & Realización de las diapositivas y preparación de la defensa ante el tribunal & 12\\\addlinespace
        \textbf{Total} & &  \bfseries 300 \\
    \end{tabular} 
    \caption{Descomposición del proyecto en tareas.}
    \label{tab:planificacion}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the question was not correct. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead`tabulary` i suggest to use `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openany]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{makecell,booktabs,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1mm}%

    \begin{document}
    XXX
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l >{\RaggedRight}X S[table-format=2.2]}
\thead{Tarea}       & \thead{Descripcion} 
                        & {\thead{Tiempo\\ estimado 
                           \normalfont en \si{\percent}}}   \\
    \addlinespace % or \midrule
Análisis            &   Recopilación de requisitos 
                        &   12\\
Diseño              &   Diseño a alto nivel de la aplicación 
                        & 20\\
AppPreferences      &   Diseño e implementación del menú 
                        de preferencias de la aplicación          
                        &   10\\
MainActivity        & Diseño e implementación de la actividad principal 
                        de la aplicación          
                        &   16\\
Dashboard           & Diseño e implementación del fragmento del dashboard
                        &   34\\
LocalXBee           &   Diseño e implementación del fragmento 
                        del XBee local
                        &   20\\
XBeeNetwork         &   Diseño e implementación del fragmento 
                        de la red de Xbees 
                        &   24\\
Log                 &   Diseño e implementación del fragmento 
                        de registro de sucesos 
                        &   6\\
BackgroundService   &   Diseño e implementación del servicio en 
                        segundo plano de la aplicación 
                        &   40\\
Servicio AIDL       &   Creación de la interfaz AIDL y 
                        wrappers necesarios
                        &   10\\
Peticiones RCI      &   Diseño e implementación del sistema de  
                        procesamiento y respuesta de las peticiones RCI
                        &   20\\
Pruebas             &   Realización de pruebas de integración 
                        de la aplicación antes del cierre del proyecto 
                        &   20\\
Documentación       &   Documentación del código 
                        &   6\\
Reuniones           &   Reuniones de seguimiento y control con 
                        los tutores de la empresa 
                        &   20\\
Memoria             &   Realización del documento para el Trabajo Fin 
                        de Grado 
                        &   30\\
Presentación        &   Realización de las diapositivas y preparación 
                        de la defensa ante el tribunal 
                        &   12\\
    \addlinespace                
\thead{Total}       &   &  {\thead{300}}
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Descomposición del proyecto en tareas.}
    \label{tab:planificacion}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

As you can see, last column type is `S` provided by package `siunitx` (the same as use @LaRiFaRi in his answer) and instead `\textbf{...} is used`thead`from package`makecell` Result is:

[image]

If you more liked that last column is right aligned, then instead of `S` use
`>{\raggedleft}X`.

Comment: Nice, but you should get rid of those white spaces. E.g. `>{\RaggedRight}X`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, yes you have right. I will correct my MWE.